# Как добавить filter к массиву объектов обратившись к длинне строки в JS (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- есть код, выводит 6 шуток. формата вопрос-ответ
- Как добавить filter убрав из вывода question, если допустим в вопросе длинна больше 50 символов.
- я пробовал что-то типо такого .filter(joke => joke.question < 50) joke.question.length и всякое подобное
- но такие конструкции не работают. выводит пустую страницу или ошибки. Явно что-то упускаю.

```js
// App.js

function App() {
  const jokeComponents = jokesData
// единственный фильтр который у меня получилось добавить :(  = c ним будет 3 шутки выводится.  
  .filter(joke => joke.id <= jokesData.length-3)
// если выводить сначала map, а после filter будет белая страница, тоже интересно было бы знать почему так?
  .map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)
    return (
        <div>
            {jokeComponents}
        </div>
    )
}


// jokeData.js  /id 1 не содержит question
const jokesData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        punchLine: "It’s hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they always take things literally."
    },
///2, 3, 4, 5 = все они содержат question и punchline
    {
        id: 6,
        question: "Did you hear about the claustrophobic astronaut?",
        punchLine: "He just needed a little space."
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const jokes = jokesData
.filter(joke => {
  //если нету вопроса или длинна вопроса больше 50 символов шутка не проходит проверку
  if (!joke.question || joke.question.length > 50) return false;
  return true;
})
.map(joke => (
  <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchline} />
));
```

Comment: - А я вот пробовал тоже через условие, всегда сталкивался с ошибкой. 
- если я напишу просто if (joke.question.length > 50) return false or true
- то всегда выводит Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
- так же если убрать ! отрицание length тоже undefined. 
А вообще спасибо.

Comment: с ! отрицанием разобрался заменил || на &&

Answer (score 1):

Работающий фильтр. Поиграться можно [тут](https://playcode.io/473434?tabs=script.js,preview,console).

```
const jokeComponents = jokesData
.filter(({ question })=> question && question.length < 50)
.map((joke) => `<Joke key=${joke.id} question=${joke.question} punchLine=${joke.punchLine} />`)
```

Comment: то что question обернуто в двойные скобки ({}) я так понял равнозначно 
.filter( question => question.question && question.question.length < 50)

Comment: @faradei это object descrution. Скорее joke.question